# Parton distribution function in terms of Fock space kets

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, hilbert-space, partons

To my understanding, I can (at least, formally) express the (unnormalized) PDF for a certain constituent of a composite state as
$$
f(x)=f\left(\dfrac{k}{K}\right)=\sum_j m_j^{(k)}|\langle\psi_j^{(k)}|\Psi^{(K)}\rangle|^2 \quad,
$$
where

- $|\Psi^{(K)}\rangle$ is a bound state whose total momentum is $K$.
- $|\psi^{(k)}_j\rangle$ are Fock space states containing $m^{(k)}_j$ constituent particles of momentum $k$.

Would you agree with such a definition?

**UPDATE**

Let me clarify what the definition above means using a simple example. Consider the Fock space of a purely bosonic $1+1$ dimensional system. Assume we want to study the bound state of total momentum $4$:
\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
|\psi\rangle=
c_1|1^4\rangle+
        c_2|2^2\rangle+
        c_3|3^1,1^1\rangle+
        c_4|4^1\rangle+
        c_5|1^2,2^1\rangle+\ldots
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}
The sum contains infinitely more terms (with negative momenta) if one quantises in equal time (e.g. $|-1,2^2\rangle$); in the light front that would be pretty much it.

Then, my guess is that the PDF should be evaluated as follows:
\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{8}
    \label{PDFex}
    f(1/4) &= 4\times|c_1|^2 + 1\times|c_3|^2  + 2\times |c_5|^2 +\ldots
    \quad&&,\\
    f(2/4) &= 2\times|c_2|^2 + 1\times |c_5|^2+\ldots
    \quad&&,\\
    f(3/4) &= 1\times|c_3|^2+\ldots
    \quad&&,\\
    f(4/4) &= 1\times|c_4|^2+\ldots
    \quad&&.
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
(again, in equal time one has infinitely more terms in each line)